# How to avoid Facebook xfbml.customerchat.js conflict with sdk.js?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have two apps on my webisite

1. Customer Chat plugin (taken from Facebook Fan Page)
2. Facebook login app

Fist one loads

- js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';

Second one loads

- js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3&appId=MYFACEBOOKID";

Both apps won't work together - if one work tne other dont.

So if Faecbook login SDK will load as first then Customer chat throw's that console notice:

> The CustomerChat plugin is no longer part of the main Facebook SDK.
>     To continue using it please use the correct SDK URL,
>     meaning replace sdk.js with sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js.
>     For more details see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk

Otherwise if only Customer chat is loaded then

> FB.login() called before FB.init().

occur...

Ideas?

Comment: You are not supposed to embed _both_, `xfbml.customerchat.js` contains the functionality of the normal SDK plus the extras.

Comment: There are two ways to initialize the JS SDK - explicitly by calling `FB.init`, or implicitly by appending these parameters in the hash portion of the SDK URL itself. So to fix the error of “FB.login() called before FB.init()”, it should be enough if you append those same values to the URL of the customer chat SDK.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's good hints!

Comment: This same problem arises when I use different libraries for FB Login and Messenger - 
`react-facebook-login` and `react-messenger-customer-chat`. How am I supposed to work around that?

Answer (score -1):

That piece of code is from Customer Chat plugin (generated by FB in Fan Page settings).

I have added one part of FB.init from Facebook login plugin inside as below:

```
<script>
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              xfbml            : true,
              version          : 'v3.3'
            });
          };
// added part START
          window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'MYAPPID', // Facebook login
              cookie     : true,
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v3.3'
            });
          };
// added part END
          (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Both plugins started to work.